# Add NavigationLink using ForEach(data: content:)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm following a Kodeco tutorial(https://www.kodeco.com/4161005-mvvm-with-combine-tutorial-for-ios) for SwiftUI and Combine which hits an API and shows the data in a list. The tutorial doesn't explain how I can navigate to a detail view from the list, and I would like to implement this, but I'm having trouble adapting my code to do this.

My List is set up like this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            characterSection
        }
        .navigationTitle("Characters")
    }
}
```

Character Section:

```
var characterSection: some View {
    Section {
        ForEach(viewModel.dataSource, content: CharacterListRowView.init(viewModel:))
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like the following to navigation to a detail screen, but I'm getting errors:

```
ForEach(viewModel.dataSource, content: CharacterListRowView.init(viewModel:)) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: viewModel.characterDetailView) {
            
    }
}
```

This obviously does not work but hopefully you can see what I am trying to do. I'm receiving these errors:

> Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred,
>
> Incorrect argument label in call (have '*:content:*:', expected '_:id:content:')
>
> Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'KeyPath<Array.Element, ID>' that does not accept a closure

Here is my row view model in case the issue is with this, could be something to do with the ID?:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CharacterRowViewModel: Identifiable {
    private let item: CharacterListResponse
    
    var id: Int {
        return item.char_id
    }
    
    var title: String {
        guard let title = item.name?.description else { return "" }
        return title
    }
    
    init(item: CharacterListResponse) {
        self.item = item
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help, I am new to SwiftUI.

Comment: Your issue is that likely `viewModel.dataSource` does not conform to `Identifiable` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable). Try adding an `id: \.self` property into the `ForEach`.

Comment: Note `NavigationView` is deprecated, use  `NavigationStack` instead. Here is the doc for how to use it:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/  Also, have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to manage data in your app:  
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app  copy and paste the example code to your app.

Answer (score 0):

One of your biggest problems is that your ForEach view is defining its contents twice, and the compiler (quite rightly) doesn't understand.

In the form you're using, ForEach takes two arguments:

- the items to loop through
- what view to generate for each item in the loop

That second argument is called `content` and it expects to be given something that receives a single item, and returns the View to use for that item.

When you use the form

```
ForEach(viewModel.dataSource, content: CharacterListRowView.init(viewModel:))
```

you're passing in a function – in this case `CharacterListRowView.init` - that receives a row view model, and returns a CharacterListRowView.

That's convenient when the `init` method matches the expected function type. But the more common form is the type you're trying to switch to - a block that receives an item, and inside which you build the view for the item. When we use that form, we usually use Swift's trailing block syntax. This allows us to omit the argument name. So when we say

```
ForEach(items) { item in 
  // view code here
}
```

it's the same as

```
ForEach(items, content: { item in 
  // view code here
})
```

Now, look again at the code you've amended:

```
ForEach(viewModel.dataSource, content: CharacterListRowView.init(viewModel:)) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: viewModel.characterDetailView) {
            
    }
}
```

Here, you're not replacing the first form of `content:` with a block form, you're attempting to provide a second `content` block. The compiler is having a meltdown because you're providing two items to something that only expects one. When this happens, sometimes the compiler's error messages can get very confusing -- it reports how what it's tried to do to make your code work hasn't worked, rather than the direct cause of the failure.

So in your ForEach loop, remove the explicit `content:`:

```swift
ForEach(viewModel.dataSource) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: viewModel.characterDetailView) {
            
    }
}
```

You may still have problems after this step, but hopefully any error messages will be a little bit easier to understand.